# Phone storage upgrade from 8gig to 16gig

Tags: internal-storage

How do I upgrade a phone with internal storage 8gigabytes to 16gigabytes

Answer (score 0):

ROM- It is a file congaing a system image of the Android OS. Like for example a Samsung android phone has some version of touchwiz android installed. You can flash in a custom Rom on your own. But sorry to say that the physical Rom cannot be replaced.

RAM- It is Random Access memory which temporarily stores your app and system data to make it faster so that your phone does not have to fetch it from the hard drive every time, and again sorry to say unlike computers and laptops in android phones the RAM cannot be replaced you are stuck with what you get.

Internal Storage- Again no you can't replace it, that is why it is important to know your needs before you buy a phone especially if the phone does not have a sd card slot.